# How can I change the .dbshell history file location

Tags: mongodb

With cmd in Win10, after terminate the mongo service, I got the error:

> Error saving history file: FileOpenFailed Unable to fopen() file
> C:\Users\鍒樺簡鏂嘰.dbshell: Access is denied.

If use **Powershell with Admin**, I will get this strange file in `C:\Users`:

```
鍒樺簡鏂嘰.dbshell
```

So, the error occurs for the reason of my non-English name directory, so how to change the location of the `.dbshell` file in MongoDB? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set it with environment variable `USERPROFILE`:

```
c:\>set USERPROFILE=C:\Temp Files\IMP

c:\>mongo --norc
MongoDB shell version v4.4.1
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("b242c05d-68d5-48a5-ba06-43665f3eb2e9") }
MongoDB server version: 4.4.1
MongoDB Enterprise > db
test
MongoDB Enterprise > print("Hello World")
Hello World
MongoDB Enterprise > exit
bye

c:\>cat "C:\Temp Files\IMP\.dbshell"
db
print("Hello World")

c:\>
```

see [How to get to the Mongo shell history file or all history on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132702/how-to-get-to-the-mongo-shell-history-file-or-all-history-on-windows)

Note, at startup the mongo shell reads file `%USERPROFILE%\.mongorc.js`, so you may have to move this file as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate your answer, I tried, but it does not work for me, win10, restarted, it seems that this env variable affects other apps like CCleaner.

Comment: Of course, it affects other application. You should set it only temporary in the command-line window where you start the mongo shell.

Comment: This is such an infuriating workaround, yet it works. So this is what I am now using. Thanks!